# $A ⊂ B$ if and only if $A − B = ∅$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I need to prove that $A ⊂ B$ if and only if $A − B = ∅$.
I have the following "proof":

$$ A \subset B \iff A - B = \emptyset$$
proof for $\implies:$

$$\forall x \in A, x \in B$$

Therefore,

$$A - B = \emptyset$$

proof for $\impliedby$:

If $$A - B = \emptyset$$
then
$$\forall x \in B, x \in A$$
since $\forall x \in B, x \in A$,

$$ A \subset B $$

However the whole thing seems to be incredibly "fragile" and relies on circular logic (see how I just switched the sets in the for all statements)

Is this a valid proof? Is there a better way to write it?

Comment: The last $\forall x \dots$ should be $\forall x \in A, x \in B$.

Comment: @Bernard Then wouldn't that make my proof the same for both?

Comment: agree with Bernard

Comment: The statement is incorrect. Alberto's answer proves the correct statement (with $\subseteq$ instead of $\subset$), but for some reason doesn't point out this important difference.

Comment: @PeterTaylor _"Some authors use the symbols ⊂ and ⊃ to indicate subset and superset respectively; that is, with the same meaning and instead of the symbols, ⊆ and ⊇"_ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset I personally find it incredibly odd for a very specific and well defined language (math) to be able to use interchangeable symbols like that. My professor uses _⊂_.

Comment: @secret your intuition that you are using circular reasoning is actually perfectly correct, and in this case that is okay because you aren't trying to prove a statement without qualification. If you show $P\iff Q$, then you cannot claim that you have shown $P$ or that you have shown $Q$ because then you would be using a circular argument incorrectly. Instead, all you are doing is showing that if we prove $P$ by other means, we get $Q$ for free and vice versa. Circular arguments are fine as long as you understand they only show equivalence of statements, not truth of statements.

Answer (score 8):

I like using "proof by contradiction" for this one, because it is logically and intuitively clear.

- (⇒) Assume $A\subseteq B$. By contradiction, suppose $A \setminus B \ne \varnothing$. Therefore there exists $x \in A \setminus B$. Therefore $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$ — a contradiction. As a result, $A \setminus B = \varnothing$.
- (⇐) Assume $A \setminus B = \varnothing$. By contradiction, suppose $A \nsubseteq B$. Therefore there exists $x \in A$ such that $x \notin B$. Therefore $x \in A \setminus B$ — a contradiction. As a result, $A \subseteq B$.

As a result, $A \subseteq B$ if and only if $A \setminus B = \varnothing$.   ◻

Comment: Actually, it is a proof by contraposition.

Comment: @Bernard: It is conventionally called proof by contradiction as he correctly states. It's called that because the goal is to derive a contradiction from the additional assumption that the desired conclusion is false. I think you know that.

Comment: I don't see the point, when proving `¬Q -> ¬P`, and say ‘suppose P is true and Q false, then deduce P is false’, to call that a proof by contradiction, if you don't need to suppose P true to deduce P false.

Answer (score 3):

One might proceed more directly by noting that $A\subseteq B$ is equivalent to $$\forall x,(x\in A)\implies(x\in B),$$ which is equivalent to $$\forall x,\neg(x\in A)\vee(x\in B).$$ The negation of this is $$\exists x:(x\in A)\wedge\neg(x\in B),$$ which is equivalent to $$\exists x:(x\in A)\wedge(x\notin B),$$ which is equivalent to $$\exists x:(x\in A\setminus B).$$ Renegating then shows us that $A\subseteq B$ is equivalent to $$\forall x,\neg(x\in A\setminus B),$$ at which point we're basically done.

Answer (score 1):

I think your proof is Ok. I just add more details.

$ (\Rightarrow) $; Suppose $ A\subset B $. Then $ \forall x\in A,x\in B $. Therefore if $ x\notin B $ then $ x\notin A $. That is if $ x\in B^{c} $ then $ x\in A^{c} $. Since $ A-B=A\cap B^{c} $ we have that $ A-B=\varnothing $.

$ (\Leftarrow) $; Conversely suppose $ A-B=\varnothing $. So $ A\cap B^{c}=\varnothing $. Therefore $ \forall x\in A,x\notin B^{c} $. Hence $ \forall x\in A,x\in B $. So we have that $ A\subset B $.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is valid if one can follow the steps, but the step from $A-B=\emptyset$ to $\forall x\in B, x\in A$ looks a bit hasty and might need some clarification. For example using the definition of $A-B$ being the set of $x: x\in A \land x \notin B$, which in turn is equivalent to $x: x\in B\rightarrow x\in A$ ($\phi\rightarrow\psi$ being the same as $\neg\phi\lor\psi$).

Answer (score 0):

Informally:
 $A - B$ is all elements of $A$ out of $B$.
and
$A \subseteq B$ means $A$ is surrounded by $B$.
so $\cdots$